# Get PathVariable using spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration

From this url
     want to extract pdf  name

```
localhost:port/server/InboundGateway/pdf/
```

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="InboundGateway"
    request-channel="request" reply-channel="response"  supported-methods="GET,POST"
    request-payload-type="java.lang.String" path="/InboundGateway/{type}"
    <int-http:header name="type" expression="#pathVariables.type" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

in the above code (int-http:header name="type" ) type will be pdf 
But how to extract its value in java code i am not able to get the HttpServletRequest

i am routing on the bases of supported-method

```
<int:router input-channel="request" expression="headers.http_requestMethod">
    <int:mapping value="POST" channel="contentDownload" />
</int:router>

<int:service-activator input-channel="contentDownload"
    method="extract" ref="downloadPayloadExtractor" output-channel="contentRouter"></int:service-activator>
```

in DownloadPayloadExtractor   i want to get the PathVariable

These are the log's

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [InboundGateway] in context with path [/mgl-crm-server] threw exception
```

org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: required header not available:  type
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:64)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:98)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:110)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:110)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:318)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:239)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:233)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:207)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:271)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.service(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: required header not available:  type
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Ternary.getValueInternal(Ternary.java:55)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:60)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:225)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:125)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:73)
    ... 42 more

Answer (score 0):

Since the Framewrok gets deal with `Message<?>` and you really gor right way to populate that `PathVariable` to the `MessageHeaders`.

The only one thing remains to improve your code is about the question "how to get access to that `type` header?". Well, you POJO method should be improved like this:

```
public Object extract(Object payload, @Header("type") String type) {
....
}
```

And that's all.

See more info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations).

**UPDATE**

> required header not available: type

Well, add this to your config:

```
<wire-tap channel="logging">

<logging-channel-adapter id="logging" log-full-message="true" level="ERROR"/>
```

And share here the logs after receiving request and until that exception.

Comment: Added some config piece to my answer.